# Learning mySQL but cant figure out this error

Tags: sql, mysql

```
select * from 
(
select year,
  subs,
  unsubs,
  LAG(subs,1) OVER(ORDER BY year) as sub_py,
  LAG(unsubs,1) OVER(ORDER BY year) as unsub_py
  FROM 
  (
    (
      SELECT
      DATE_FORMAT(subscription_started,"%Y") as year,
      SUM(Case WHEN subscription_started is not null then 1 else 0 end) as subs
      FROM user_churn
      group by year
    ) as s
    INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT
      DATE_FORMAT(subscription_ended,"%Y") as year_unsub,
      SUM(Case WHEN subscription_ended is not null then 1 else 0 end) as unsubs
      FROM user_churn
      group by year_unsub
    ) as us
      on s.year=us.year_unsub
  ) as main
)
```

The sub-query is working fine, but it fails when I add the topmost query. Error is on [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k7XjVEqFm95XkkzgYFkMw7/0#&togetherjs=No8IA5iJt6)

Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as main )' at line 26

I am trying to add top query because I have to perform more operations on it.

Comment: I think you have an extra bracketed expression in your `FROM` clause - either add a `SELECT * FROM` or remove the `(` and `) as main` lines.  Also your outermost `SELECT` is perhaps not needed

Comment: Your FROM clause is empty on DBFiddle

Comment: I was just using it keep it structured. @Rob Eyre and nbk have answered the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must remove more than one bracket

Keeping all brackets on the same distance from he left is helpful to have clean code

```
select * from 
(
select year,
  subs,
  unsubs,
  LAG(subs,1) OVER(ORDER BY year) as sub_py,
  LAG(unsubs,1) OVER(ORDER BY year) as unsub_py
  FROM 
  
    (
      SELECT
      DATE_FORMAT(subscription_started,"%Y") as year,
      SUM(Case WHEN subscription_started is not null then 1 else 0 end) as subs
      FROM user_churn
      group by year
    ) as s
    INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT
      DATE_FORMAT(subscription_ended,"%Y") as year_unsub,
      SUM(Case WHEN subscription_ended is not null then 1 else 0 end) as unsubs
      FROM user_churn
      group by year_unsub
    ) as us
      on s.year=us.year_unsub
) as drv
```